# Upgrade pip to newest version on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, ubuntu-16.04, pip

I'm trying to upgrade pip into the newest version (old version 9.0.1 and newest version 19.3.1. using the following commands.

```
pip install --upgrade pip

sudo apt-get upgrade pip
```

But it won't upgrade it with the following error:

```
**$ pip install --upgrade pip**

Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/larz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "/home/larz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,

  File "/home/larz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs

  File "/home/larz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)

  File "/home/larz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,

  File "/home/larz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

  File "/home/larz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)

  File "/home/larz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip'
```

I need to install keras. While I was installing it asked me to upgrade pip. When I try to upgrade pip I'm getting above errors

Comment: Can you please copy the error and paste it on your question? Images are unnecessary if the information is only text

Comment: Sure: I have updated

Comment: Since you're upgrading `pip` itself, run with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `python2.7` instead of the latest `python3.8`? `pip` is used with `python2.*` and `pip3` is used with `python3.*`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my number one tip: **Do not use `sudo` with `pip`.**  You don't need it.

Instead, use a user-level Python distribution installed via `pyenv`. That way you don't risk yourself messing around with system-level frameworks (and hence creating a problem removing dependencies etc.).

#### Install Pyenv

All you have to do is:

- Run the [`pyenv` installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer)
- Follow the instructions
- Install the Python versions you need
- Choose which Python version you want to use for a given directory, or globally

For example, to install 3.7, check which versions are available:

```
pyenv install -l | grep 3.7
```

Then run:

```
pyenv install 3.7.4
```

#### Switch to the new version

Now, you can choose your Python version:

```
pyenv global 3.7.4
```

This switches your `python` to point to 3.7.4. If you want the “old” system python, run:

```
pyenv global system
```

To check which Python versions are available, run `pyenv versions`.

#### Upgrade `pip`

Once you've switched to a Pyenv version, you can run `pip` without `sudo`, and install/upgrade packages easily — without interfering with your system Python:

```
pyenv global 3.7.4
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `apt-get` to update pip. The newest version of `pip` available through `apt-get` is old.

**Quick solution:**

As @kenorb is saying in the comments, you can upgrade `pip` using `pip` with `sudo` like this:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Proper solution:**

Use `pyenv` - see the answer by @slhck

Comment: Yes thank you both of you. I solved it using above method. Thanks again  kenorb and @curusarn. 

Yes I just found that pip3 used for python3. How can I set python3 as default. I tried to remove python2. But I end up with mess removing all dependencies etc..

Comment: You need to install python3 separately: `sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip && sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`. Install any python3 package using `sudo pip3 install package_name`. To change the default python you can add this line to your `~/.bashrc`: `alias python=python3`
Note that this only changes the default when you use it in the terminal. It's not a very good idea to change the system-wide default because some programs may only work with python2. Also, you still need to use `sudo pip3` to install packages for python3.

Comment: I prefer not teaching users to use/require `sudo` for managing Python under Linux. It just creates problems down the line when people try to install/uninstall packages and inadvertently removing required system dependencies.